# typo3 redirection with baseurl

Tags: typo3, base-url

I started working as a working student in a company that hosted their website with typo3. In order to test a few extensions and stuff, I moved the whole typo3 folders to a local machine and configured a new typo3 version.

Everything works fine now except the redirection. When I browse to localhost/ it shows me the index page. But when I click on a link it redirects me to the actual website like www.companyname.com/link1 instead of localhost/link1. I think it has something to do with changing the baseurl in the typo3 config but when I changed the baseurl in the config from http://companyname.com/ to localhost/ it didnt change anything and still redirects me to the actual website when clicking on a link.

Is there anything else I need to do in order to make my copy get to work on localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Links are cached in TYPO3, so it might be that you didn't clear the cache so TYPO3 is still delivering the cached links.

It could also be that absRefPrefix is set.

Comment: +1. Check the source code to see what is the `<base>` tag set to and what the links point to.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below;

```
domain = localhost
absRefPrefix = Typ62
```

Typ62 = the Folder name in which the typo3 file/folders are there